# derivative of lebesgue integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose we have $f \in L(I)$ and derivative $f'$ exists almost everywhere .
It is $f'$ measurable ? I have no idea how to begin to construct the proof .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $f'(x) = \lim_{n\to +\infty} n(f(x+\frac{1}{n}) - f(x) )$ almost everywhere

So $f'$ is a simple limit of measurable functions hence measurable

Comment: I feel foolish , sometimes it is so simple the proof ...(sorry for my english)